# Shouldn't UIRecognizers fire when a subview is touched?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, subview

Views in my iPad app behave as if they prevent their superview's gesture recognizers from firing when the user initiates such gesture in that view.

Is this expected?
How can I remove that shielding behavior?
What are good practices to debug gesture recognizers?

In more details:

The main "canvas" view of my application, lets the user adds shapes to it with a "long double tap". I attached a gesture recognizer for such gestures to the main view. That works very well: the main view gets called, and reacts by adding a shape to the main view.

Shapes are implemented as subviews of the main view. When the user long-double-taps in the main view, my code instanciate a shape subview, and adds it to the main view. Shape views can be moved around with a long-single-tap recognizer. So I also attach a gesture recognizer for long-single-taps to every shape view. That works very well: the shape view gets called and lets the user move it in the canvas.

However, when the user long-double-taps in a shape view, nothing happens: the shape view is not called, which is expected since it doesn't have a gesture recognizer for long-double-taps. But the main view is not called either. I had thought that since the gesture was not recognized by the shape view, then it would be propagated up in the responder chain to the main view. But this doesn't happen.

My intent is to let the user add overlapping shapes to the main view, so that a long-double-tap on a shape would also add a new shape to the main view.

What could I have missed?

I can of course add a long-double-tap recognizer to shape views, and from there, either forward the gesture to the main view or handle the gesture directly in a way similar to what I do in the main view.

But this sounds wasteful, and more importantly, I'd like to understand the behavior.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: When you double long tap on a subview does it fire the single long tap?

Comment: yes, the subview single-long-tap fires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should as far as I can see pass the message along out of the box.

To ensure both `gestureRecognizers` are not fired you need to do something like:

```
[longPress requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleLongPress];
```

**Update**

Just free styling here but if you want to limit the gesture to one view you could try playing with the gesture delegate (this will only respond if the touched view is `self.view`)

```
self.myGesture.delegate = self;
```

In your controller do something like:

```
//.h
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
// ...
@end

//.m
@implementation MyController

//...

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
{
    BOOL shouldReceiveTouch = YES;

    if (gestureRecognizer == self.myGesture) {
        shouldReceiveTouch = (touch.view == self.view);
    }

    return shouldReceiveTouch;
}

//...

@end
```

**NB** I haven't tested this but I will update when I test it later.

Comment: Yes that was it. I hadn't configured the recognizers dependencies. I somehow thought that recognizers on other views were independent, which they aren't. Makes coupling too strong for my taste, but I really can't see how to avoid that.